# How to add lengths of second element in a list of tuples in one pass in spark?

Tags: python, lambda, apache-spark, pyspark, reduce

I have a list of tuples:

```
myTuples = sc.parallelize([('ID1',['r','t','q']),
                           ('ID2',['b','u','n']),
                           ('ID4',['n','n'])])
```

And I want to count the sum of all of the lengths of all of the second elements in the tuples.  So, in this case, that would be `3+3+2=8`.

I know it is possible to do this in two passes:

```
countTupleLengths = myTuples.map(lambda aTuple: len(aTuple[1]))
LengthSum = countTupleLengths.reduce(lambda a, b: a + b)
```

But conceptually it is possible to do this in one pass.  The length could be computed, and then added to the next length that is computed, etc.  I have a feeling I could use `reduce` for this, but I was unable to resolve this because of the different datatypes between a length (integer) and a list:

```
# throws an error because len() produces an integer,
# and len(integer) doesn't make sense when reduce makes its recursive call
LengthSum = myTuples.reduce(lambda aTuple, bTuple: len(aTuple) + len(bTuple))
```

How do I do this in one pass?  Or, does `pyspark` optimize this under the hood and actually do it in one pass due to its lazy evaluation?

Comment: The problem is that `aTuple` performs as a `tuple` just for the first iteration, after that it behaves more like an accumulator `integer` and wouldn't work as you expect.

Comment: yeah, i know.  that's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: What you want happens automatically because transformations on `RDDs` are lazy.

Comment: Well, the datasets I'm talking about can be enormous and on a distributed file system.  Still no performance gain?

Answer (score 2):

Spark performs its computations in memory, so you shouldn't take too much of a performance hit doing a map, then a reduce. That said, if you want to do the whole computation with one operation, you can use Spark accumulators.

`my_job.py`

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

def main():
    sc = SparkContext(appName='myapp')

    myTuples = sc.parallelize([('ID1',['r','t','q']),
                               ('ID2',['b','u','n']),
                               ('ID4',['n','n'])])
    acc = sc.accumulator(0)

    def addToAcc(val):
        acc.add(len(val[1]))

    myTuples.foreach(addToAcc)
    print acc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To run:

```
$ ./spark-submit /path/to/my_job.py 
8
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. I don't think it is worth all the fuss but here you are:

```py
from operator import add

myTuples.aggregate(
    0,  # zero value is zero
    # add len of current to accumulator where acc: int, x: (_, list)
    lambda acc, x: acc + len(x[1]),
    # add two accumulators, equivalent to lambda x, y: x + y where x: int, y: int
    add)
```

Regarding performance gains all depends on a context. If there is enough memory, so intermediate results doesn't have to be spilled to disk, then any gains should be negligible. Ignoring costs of running iteration itself it doesn't improve overall computational complexity after all.